# DataFrame explode list of JSON objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing

I have JSON data in the following format:

```
{
     "date": 100
     "userId": 1
     "data": [
         {
             "timeStamp": 101,
             "reading": 1
         },
         {
             "timeStamp": 102,
             "reading": 2
         }
     ]
 }
 {
     "date": 200
     "userId": 1
     "data": [
         {
             "timeStamp": 201,
             "reading": 3
         },
         {
             "timeStamp": 202,
             "reading": 4
         }
     ]
 }
```

I read it into Spark SQL:

```
val df = SQLContext.read.json(...)
df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- date: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- userId: long (nullable = true)
//  |-- data: array (nullable = true)
//  |     |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |     |    |-- timeStamp: double (nullable = true)
//  |     |    |-- reading: double (nullable = true)
```

I would like to transform it in order to have one row per reading. To my understanding, every transformation should produce a new DataFrame, so the following should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
val exploded = df
    .withColumn("reading", explode(df("data.reading")))
    .withColumn("timeStamp", explode(df("data.timeStamp")))
    .drop("data")
exploded.printSchema
// root
//  |-- date: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- userId: long (nullable = true)
//  |-- timeStamp: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- reading: double (nullable = true)
```

The resulting schema is correct, but I get every value twice:

```
exploded.show
// +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
// |       date|     userId|  timeStamp|    reading|
// +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
// |        100|          1|        101|          1|
// |        100|          1|        101|          1|
// |        100|          1|        102|          2|
// |        100|          1|        102|          2|
// |        200|          1|        201|          3|
// |        200|          1|        201|          3|
// |        200|          1|        202|          4|
// |        200|          1|        202|          4|
// +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

My feeling is that there is something about the lazy evaluation of the two explodes that I don't understand.

Is there a way to get the above code to work? Or should I use a different approach all together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The resulting schema is correct, but I get every value twice

While schema is correct the output you've provided doesn't reflect actual result. In practice you'll get Cartesian product of `timeStamp` and `reading` for each input row.

> My feeling is that there is something about the lazy evaluation

No, it has nothing to do with lazy evaluation. The way you use `explode` is just wrong. To understand what is going on lets trace execution for `date` equal 100:

```
val df100 = df.where($"date" === 100)
```

step by step. First `explode` will generate two rows, one for 1 and one for 2:

```
val df100WithReading = df100.withColumn("reading", explode(df("data.reading")))

df100WithReading.show
// +------------------+----+------+-------+
// |              data|date|userId|reading|
// +------------------+----+------+-------+
// |[[1,101], [2,102]]| 100|     1|      1|
// |[[1,101], [2,102]]| 100|     1|      2|
// +------------------+----+------+-------+
```

The second explode generate two rows (`timeStamp` equal 101 and 102) for **each row** from the previous step:

```
val df100WithReadingAndTs = df100WithReading
  .withColumn("timeStamp", explode(df("data.timeStamp")))

df100WithReadingAndTs.show
// +------------------+----+------+-------+---------+
// |              data|date|userId|reading|timeStamp|
// +------------------+----+------+-------+---------+
// |[[1,101], [2,102]]| 100|     1|      1|      101|
// |[[1,101], [2,102]]| 100|     1|      1|      102|
// |[[1,101], [2,102]]| 100|     1|      2|      101|
// |[[1,101], [2,102]]| 100|     1|      2|      102|
// +------------------+----+------+-------+---------+
```

If you want correct results `explode` data and `select` afterwards:

```
val exploded = df.withColumn("data", explode($"data"))
  .select($"userId", $"date",
    $"data".getItem("reading"),  $"data".getItem("timestamp"))

exploded.show
// +------+----+-------------+---------------+
// |userId|date|data[reading]|data[timestamp]|
// +------+----+-------------+---------------+
// |     1| 100|            1|            101|
// |     1| 100|            2|            102|
// |     1| 200|            3|            201|
// |     1| 200|            4|            202|
// +------+----+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: abbreviated form for inner field selection will work too :  `df.withColumn("data",explode($"data")).select($"data.reading", $"data.timestamp", $"date",$"userId").foreach(println)`