# Unable to explode() Map[String, Struct] in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Been struggling with this for a while and still can't make my mind around it.

I'm trying to flatMap (or use `.withColumn` with `explode()` instead as it seems easier so I don't lose column names), but I'm always getting the error `UDTF expected 2 aliases but got 'name' instead`.

I've revisited some similar questions but none of them shed some light as their schemas are too simple.

The column of the schema I'm trying to perform flatMap with is the following one...

```
StructField(CarMake,
  StructType(
    List(
      StructField(
        Models,
        MapType(
          StringType,
          StructType(
            List(
              StructField(Variant, StringType),
              StructField(GasOrPetrol, StringType)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ))
```

What I'm trying to achieve by calling explode() like this...

```
carsDS
      .withColumn("modelsAndVariant", explode($"carmake.models"))
```

...is to achieve a Row without that nested Map and Struct so I get as many rows as variants are.

**Example input**

```
(country: Sweden, carMake: Volvo, carMake.Models: {"850": ("T5", "petrol"), "V50": ("T5", "petrol")})
```

**Example output**

```
(country: Sweden, carMake: Volvo, Model: "850", Variant: "T5", GasOrPetrol: "petrol"}
(country: Sweden, carMake: Volvo, Model: "V50", Variant: "T5", GasOrPetrol: "petrol"}
```

Basically leaving the nested Map with its inner Struct all in the same level.

Comment: please add some sample data (code) which can be used to answer the question (i.e. a programmatically created dataframe)

Comment: see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192994/spark-dataframe-exploding-a-map-with-the-key-as-a-member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
case class Models(variant:String, gasOrPetrol:String)
case class CarMake(brand:String, models : Map[String, Models] )
case class MyRow(carMake:CarMake)

val df = List(
  MyRow(CarMake("volvo",Map(
    "850" -> Models("T5","petrol"),
    "V50" -> Models("T5","petrol")
  )))
).toDF()

df.printSchema()

df.show()
```

gives

```
root
 |-- carMake: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- models: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- variant: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- gasOrPetrol: string (nullable = true)


+--------------------+
|             carMake|
+--------------------+
|[volvo, [850 -> [...|
+--------------------+
```

now explode, note that `withColumn` does not work because `èxplode` on a map returns 2 columns (`key` and `value`), so you need to use `select`:

```
val cols: Array[Column] = df.columns.map(col)

df
  .select((cols:+explode($"carMake.models")):_*)
  .select((cols:+$"key".as("model"):+$"value.*"):_*)
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+--------------------+-----+-------+-----------+
|             carMake|model|variant|gasOrPetrol|
+--------------------+-----+-------+-----------+
|[volvo, [850 -> [...|  850|     T5|     petrol|
|[volvo, [850 -> [...|  V50|     T5|     petrol|
+--------------------+-----+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer! Sorry for not giving code to quick test, I had to leave in a rush and couldn't come back to this until now, really appreciated :)